# how to configure Apache Directory Server without GUI

Tags: ldap

I am new to Apache Directory Server (apacheds-2.0.0-M23) , and the official documentation about it is quite incomplete.
I know that is possible to configure the server easily using Apache Directory Studio GUI, but i want the server to be deployed on a remote server not having a graphic interface that means, no way to use apache Directory Studio.

i have tried to read [this](http://directory.apache.org/apacheds/advanced-ug/2.1-config-description.html) , then i have created a new partition using apache studio to see what files have been created on the disk. Effectively, there are folders and .ldif files created with attributes listed from the documentation. The problem here is that there are some auto-generated values for mandatory attributes such as entryCSN from this [list](http://directory.apache.org/apacheds/advanced-ug/2.1-config-description.html#indexes) for the file indexes.ldif

So can someone tell me how to :

```
Add a partition, a JDBM one
Import an ldif file of entries under that partition
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen the [Documentation about creating partitions](https://directory.apache.org/apacheds/basic-ug/1.4.3-adding-partition.html)? The first part describes how to add them using Apache Directory Studio GUI. But at the end there is an example for Java and also using a `ldif` file:

```
dn: ads-partitionId=example,ou=partitions,ads-directoryServiceId=default,ou=config
objectclass: top
objectClass: ads-base
objectclass: ads-partition
objectclass: ads-jdbmPartition
ads-partitionSuffix: dc=example,dc=com
ads-contextentry:: ZG46IGRjPWV4YW1wbGUsZGM9Y29tCmRjOiBleGFtcGxlCm9iamVjdGNsYXNzOiBkb21haW4Kb2JqZWN0Y2xhc3M6IHRvcAoK
ads-jdbmpartitionoptimizerenabled: TRUE
ads-partitioncachesize: 10000
ads-partitionsynconwrite: TRUE
ads-partitionid: example
ads-enabled: TRUE
```

You should be able to generate a new partition by placing the above `ldif` before the `ldif` of your partition content (OUs, Users and so on). Be sure to keep attention on the `ads-contextentry` attribute which contains the partition DN in base64 encoded format like this for the example partition:

```
dn: dc=example,dc=com
dc: example
objectclass: domain
objectclass: top
```

Comment: `ERR_268 Cannot find a partition for dc=example,dc=com`

Comment: That is a default partition from ApacheDS which got created automatically after installation. Maybe some switch was used that prevent ApacheDS from creating it _or_ instead create some custom one. You can use e.g. Apache Directory Studio to see which partitions exist on your DC.

Answer (score 0):

For example, to create a domain like:

```
dn: dc=marmoser,dc=local
dc: marmoser
objectclass: domain
objectclass: top
```

you have to encode it into ads-contextentry by base64(dn: dc=marmoser,dc=local\n...)

Save this buffer into marmoser-partition.ldif

```
dn: ads-partitionId=marmoser,ou=partitions,ads-directoryServiceId=default,ou=config
objectclass: top
objectClass: ads-base
objectclass: ads-partition
objectclass: ads-jdbmPartition
ads-enabled: TRUE
ads-partitionSuffix: dc=marmoser,dc=local
ads-contextentry:: ZG46IGRjPW1hcm1vc2VyLGRjPWxvY2FsCmRjOiBtYXJtb3NlcgpvYmplY3RjbGFzczogZG9tYWluCm9iamVjdGNsYXNzOiB0b3AK
ads-partitioncachesize: 1000
ads-partitionsynconwrite: TRUE
ads-partitionid: marmoser

dn: ou=indexes,ads-partitionId=marmoser,ou=partitions,ads-directoryServiceId=default,ou=config
objectclass: top
objectclass: organizationalUnit
ou: indexes

dn: ads-indexAttributeId=uid,ou=indexes,ads-partitionId=marmoser,ou=partitions,ads-directoryServiceId=default,ou=config
objectclass: top
objectclass: ads-base
objectclass: ads-index
objectclass: ads-jdbmIndex
ads-indexAttributeId: uid
ads-enabled: TRUE
ads-indexhasreverse: FALSE

dn: ads-indexAttributeId=dc,ou=indexes,ads-partitionId=marmoser,ou=partitions,ads-directoryServiceId=default,ou=config
objectclass: top
objectclass: ads-base
objectclass: ads-index
objectclass: ads-jdbmIndex
ads-indexAttributeId: dc
ads-enabled: TRUE
ads-indexhasreverse: FALSE
```

Execute

```
ldapmodify -h localhost -p 10389 -D "uid=admin,ou=system" -w secret -a -f marmoser-partition.ldif

service apacheds restart
```